# Parse HTML and replace content in DIV

Tags: php, html, parsing

I want to know how i can find the DIV tag in a HTML page. This is because i want to replace the links inside that DIV with different links. I do not understand what exact code i require.

Comment: @Blake it seems that he tried asking the same thing another time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215357/change-html-contents-using-php :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that PHP won't do anything *client side*. But you should already know it.
you should use file_get_contents to read the webpage as a string (or what is provided by a library for html parsing).

There is already a question that explain how to parse html in any way: [Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

If it doesn't fit your needs, try searching it on google: *php html parsing*, I found some libraries

For example this library I've found allows you to find all  tags: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Notice that this is not a great approach and I suggest you change your html page to be a PHP page, and insert some code in place of A tags. This will make everything easier.

Last thing, if the html page is static (it doesn't change), you can use easily line counting to get contents from X line to Y line, put your customized A-tags and then read from J to the end of file.

Good luck anyway.